# Sort,Unique and displaying max count

Tags: unix, sorting, awk, uniq

In the table below, Remove duplicates and for some point of time say 12:06 only maximum count value should be displayed

```
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 693 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 797 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 717 Count
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 700 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 726 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 850 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 900 Count
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 693 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 797 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 950 Count
```

Output should look like below:

```
3/12/2013 12:00 639 Count
3/12/2013 12:06 700 Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636 Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649 Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658 Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926 Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721 Count
3/12/2013 12:42 850 Count
3/12/2013 12:48 900 Count
```

Comment: I need to a Unix command to perform this operation

Comment: What have you tried so far?  This is a question and answer site, and I see no question (nor any attempt to solve the problem yourself before seeking help).

Comment: you may want to look at Microsoft Excel 2013 for this...

Comment: @summea on `unix` hmmmmm?

Comment: @sudo_O is that like NT?

Comment: cat Task1.txt | sort | uniq | sort -k1  | sort -um -k2.1,2.0 i tried this command and i am looking for a alternative command

Comment: @summea haha.. no! @ user2162716 lucky for you I have added two.

Comment: comment on NT goes into my hall of fame :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ sort -k2,2 -rk3,3  file | uniq -w15 | sort -k2,2
3/12/2013 12:00 639     Count
3/12/2013 12:06 700     Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636     Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649     Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658     Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926     Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721     Count
3/12/2013 12:42 850     Count
3/12/2013 12:48 950     Count
```

Or with some `awk`:

```
$ awk '{if($3>a[$1" "$2])a[$1" "$2]=$3}END{for(k in a)print k,a[k],"\tCount"}' file | sort
3/12/2013 12:00 639     Count
3/12/2013 12:06 700     Count
3/12/2013 12:12 636     Count
3/12/2013 12:18 649     Count
3/12/2013 12:24 658     Count
3/12/2013 12:30 926     Count
3/12/2013 12:36 721     Count
3/12/2013 12:42 850     Count
3/12/2013 12:48 950     Count
```